# After stopping MonetDB, mserver still appear to be running, and restart is now impossible. Does anyone know why?

Tags: monetdb

I'm new to using MonetDB for my data.  My dataset is currently about 1TB in size (spread across lots of tables).

About an hour or two ago, I ran `monetdbd stop db` and `monetdb stop db` (both the dbfarm and the database are named "db").

I would have expected this to stop every MonetDB process, but I just noticed via htop that there are several `mserver` processes still running.

Additionally, when I try to run `monetdb start db`, I get an error (see the below logs).  I suspect the reason monetdb crashes when I try to restart has something to do with the `stop` command from earlier not yet being totally finished with the shutdown procedure, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
2023-03-15 17:13:29 MSG merovingian[247517]: caught SIGTERM, starting shutdown sequence
2023-03-15 17:11:16 MSG control[247517]: (local): served status list
2023-03-15 17:13:29 MSG control[247517]: control channel closed
2023-03-15 17:13:30 MSG merovingian[247517]: Merovingian 11.45.7 stopped
2023-03-15 17:13:35 MSG merovingian[247584]: Merovingian 11.45.7 (Sep2022) starting
2023-03-15 17:13:35 MSG merovingian[247584]: monitoring dbfarm /root/db
2023-03-15 17:13:35 MSG merovingian[247584]: accepting connections on TCP socket 0.0.0.0:50000
2023-03-15 17:13:35 MSG merovingian[247584]: accepting connections on UNIX domain socket /tmp/.s.monetdb.50000
2023-03-15 17:13:35 MSG discovery[247584]: listening for UDP messages on 0.0.0.0:50000 
2023-03-15 17:13:35 MSG control[247584]: accepting connections on UNIX domain socket /tmp/.s.merovingian.50000
2023-03-15 17:13:53 MSG control[247584]: (local): served status list
2023-03-15 17:13:53 MSG merovingian[247584]: database 'db' has crashed after start on 2023-03-15 17:11:35, attempting restart, up min/avg/max: 12m/13h/1d, crash average: 1.00 0.40 0.13 (6-2=4) 
2023-03-15 17:13:54 MSG db[247593]: arguments: /usr/bin/mserver5 --dbpath=/root/db/db --set=merovingian_uri=mapi:monetdb://research:50000/db --set=mapi_listenaddr=none --set=mapi_usock=/root/db/db/.mapi.sock --set=monet_vault_key=/root/db/db/.vaultkey --set=gdk_nr_threads=12 --set=max_clients=64 --set=sql_optimizer=default_pipe
2023-03-15 17:14:00 MSG merovingian[247584]: database 'db' (-1) has crashed with signal SIGSEGV (dumped core)
2023-03-15 17:14:00 ERR control[247584]: (local): failed to fork mserver: database 'db' has crashed after starting, manual intervention needed, check monetdbd's logfile (merovingian.log) for details
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

EDIT: After searching, it appears to be a known issue.  See other GitHub issues below:
https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/issues/3243
https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/issues/7152

Comment: Update: I found a few issues on the GitHub that give the impression that this is a known and unresolved issue in MonetDB.  I consider the data lost, and have started creating routine backups of the MonetDB dbfarm directory.  Restarts can just corrupt the DB sometimes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Can you point to the GH issues that you found looking similar to what you are experiencing ?
Also, double check if the issues that you find and the MonetDB version that they relate to match MonetDB version that you are running.

Maybe you could file a new GH issue if this is something new and provide a BT eg.

Regards.

Comment: I will add those now!  I think the issue is already known (via the GitHub issues I'm linking), so I'll hold off on posting another issue to the GitHub repo.